# React PureComponent updates when props and state did not change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently playing around with `ReactJS`' `PureComponent`.  I have a simple component which just shows some text inside nested `PureComponent`s:

```
export class Test extends React.Component<ITestProps> {
    componentDidMount(): void {
        window.setInterval(() => this.forceUpdate(), 1500);
    }

    private readonly extraSmall = { size: 10 };

    render(): JSX.Element {
        console.log("render Login");
        return (
            <Bootstrap.Container fluid={true}>
                <Bootstrap.Row>
                    <Bootstrap.Col xs={this.extraSmall}>
                        RENDERED!
                    </Bootstrap.Col>
                </Bootstrap.Row>
            </Bootstrap.Container>
        );
    }
}
```

I've exptected that the `render` would only be called once on each component. `Container`, `Row` and `Col` are all `PureComponent`s.
However, they all got called once every 1.5 seconds and I don't get the point why.

What I have understood from the docs is, that even if the parent is updated during `forceUpdate()`, each child will call the `shouldComponentUpdate` which should return `false` for each child of `Test` or at least `Container`.

But in console is see `render Login`, `render Container`, `render Row` and `render Col`. But `Container`'s `props` or `state` did not change. So why is there a re-render happening?

From the docs:

> Calling forceUpdate() will cause render() to be called on the component, skipping shouldComponentUpdate(). 
>   This will trigger the normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the shouldComponentUpdate() 
>   method of each child. React will still only update the DOM if the markup changes.

So even if this component does not make any real-life sense, it should not re-render at least `Row` and `Col`.

Comment: maybe "forceUpdate" has priority over shouldComponentUpdate. You can look the original reactjs code about forceUpdate

Comment: From the docs it says this about `forceUpdate()`: `This will trigger the normal lifecycle methods for child components, including the shouldComponentUpdate()`

Comment: To debug it further I'd create a tiny component with a custom `sCU` method and put a breakpoint inside. Then I'd see whether it's called at all and what happens if I return `false`.

Comment: Should you be using `this.forceUpdate.bind(this)` when setting the interval? It's getting called without `this`.  Not sure if it's related

Comment: @JuanMendes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Comment: @zerkms I did already in `Container`. Returned `nextProps.fluid !== this.props.fluid` and `Row` & `Col` have never been called afterwards

Comment: @KingKerosin so now take a debugger, as I suggested, and check **why** behaviour is different for `Row` and `Col`. If `forceUpdate` respects `sCU` - something else is happening, and a debugger would almost instantly show you what exactly.

Comment: @zerkms doesn't matter, unless they actually call the function, `window.setInterval(() => this.forceUpdate(), 1500);`. Did you think I didn't know what arrow functions are?

Comment: @JuanMendes it does matter, `this` is lexically scoped so would be exactly the same as `this` inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: @JuanMendes "Did you think I didn't know what arrow functions are?" --- I really did not think anything about you, I just corrected your not so accurate comment. There is nothing wrong with their `window.setInterval` code, it works thanks to the lexical `this` context introduced by arrow functions, hence I provided a link which explains it.

Comment: @zerkms You are misreading something, as the code stands, it's not going to call anything in the interval callback, you just have a loose reference to a function. It would have to be what I said in my above comment or `window.setInterval( this.forceUpdate.bind(this), 1500)`

Comment: @zerkms & @JuanMendes: My fault. I forgot the `()` (but only in the sample code). I've added `sCU` to `Row` and `Col`. Both get called each 1.5 seconds

Comment: @JuanMendes oh gosh, I'm not sure why I was seeing `()` there all the time, my apologies. /me feeling dumb.

Comment: @KingKerosin would the problem reproduce if you don't use `forceUpdate` but geniunely update the state instead? eg: `this.setState({ now: new Date() });`

Comment: @zerkms If using `setTimeout(this.forceUpdate, 1500)` it all gets only called once. So the issue (at least for me) was never the component. It's how the `forceUpdate` has been called. Still don't know why the one is re-rendering each child and the other one not

Comment: @KingKerosin /me is whispering: take a debugger and answer your own question ;-P

Comment: Can't answer this thoroughly with full confidence, but there is definitely a factor: The function in your `setTimeout` is an anonymous function( first way you wrote it), which means it's impossible to hold a reference to it when there is an equality check. Writing it as a named function (second way) allows a reference.

Comment: @KingKerosin Could you provide the implementation of Bootstrap components?

Comment: @KingKerosin I tried your code and my Bootstrap components render only once.

Comment: @zerkms That's why I'm extra careful if I'm posting something that goes against what someone who has high rep (as I was before I posted that you were incorrect). The only way your comment would make sense is if I did not know how arrow functions work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am too late, but I will leave this answer for other users. 
The reason is you are using `forceUpdate` which ignores `shouldComponentUpdate`.

The reason of `forceUpdate` existence is to make component re-render again and again ignoring props or state update, because sometimes it is needed.

Docs reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate